# Is there a size limit for Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a maximum size that the forms can be? I am creating a very large form and wonder if there will be any performance or loading issues as the form gets larger.  Would it be better if I split the form into several smaller forms? What is your recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

There is not a technical limit, as we have been developing the underlying frameworks for Cognito Forms for over five years, and have spent a lot of time optimizing them for extremely large forms.  For example, all of the calculations and dynamic behavior on our forms are event-driven, so calculations and HTML rendering are only triggered for the fields that are dependent on the fields that change.

Having said this, Cognito Forms runs entirely in the browser using HTML5, JavaScript and CSS, so they are dependent on the performance of the browser and hardware.  This means there will be cases on older devices where extremely large forms will not perform as well as smaller forms.

If you have a really long form, I recommend using page breaks instead of separate forms.  We specifically implemented page breaks in a way that maximizes performance by only rendering the page that is visible (versus rendering all of them and hide/show).  This will improve the performance of really long forms.